# How can I install the postgresql-contrib module in an existing database?

Tags: postgresql, module

I'm using `postgresql 9.1.6` on CentOS. I would like to install the [postgresql-contrib](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/contrib.html) module using a binary file, but I can't find it online. I'm unsure if I can install this after already installing `postgresql`. Is it possible to do this?

I installed `postgresql` in the following way:

```
wget http://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/source/v9.1.6/postgresql-9.1.6.tar.gz
tar -xzf postgresql-9.1.6.tar.gz 
cd postgresql-9.1.6./configure --prefix=$HOME
make 
make install
```

I am currently using the databases within this install and would prefer not to reinstall it (if possible).

I understand that once I install this I can use a function in the following way:

```
create extension tablefunc ;
```

EDIT: If I followed the instructions from [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/contrib.html), does  `gmake` and `gmake install` affect an existing database?

Comment: With 9.1 you should use `create extension tablefunc`. Did you try that?

Comment: Yes, that's right; I did that after installing (I'll update my question).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You might be hard pressed to find the contrib modules as binary distributions; however, the very page you linked has explicit instructions on how to build the contrib modules:

When building from the source distribution, these modules are not built automatically. You can build and install all of them by running

```
gmake
gmake install
```

in the contrib directory of a configured source tree; or to build and install just one selected module, do the same in that module's subdirectory.

Alternatively, you could try using yum (the package is postgresql-contrib.x86_64), but I can't vouch for the results of this if you installed Postgres from source.

Comment: Yes, I realized that the instructions are there - but would that reinstall the database or just add the `contrib` module and not affect anything else?

Comment: As long as you're in the contrib directory, it will only build and install the contrib modules.

Comment: "sudo yum install postgresql-contrib.x86_64" fixed my issue. Thanks.